# How to catch the OnScroll Event on RichEdit?

Tags: windows, delphi, events, message

i created a custom Rich which has a scrollPos event.

so i have this code:

```
procedure TCustomRich.WMVScroll(var Msg : TWMVScroll);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Msg.ScrollCode in [SB_THUMBTRACK, SB_THUMBPOSITION]) then
    FScrollY := Msg.Pos;
  if Assigned(OnScroll) then
    OnScroll(Self, FScrollX, FScrollY);
end;

procedure TCustomRich.WMHScroll(var Msg : TWMVScroll);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Msg.ScrollCode in [SB_THUMBTRACK, SB_THUMBPOSITION]) then
    FScrollX := Msg.Pos;
  if Assigned(OnScroll) then
    OnScroll(Self, FScrollX, FScrollY);
end;
```

but the problem is it wont trigger when it scroll using the keys or mouse wheels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TRichEdit` can be an awkward customer in this regard. You need to handle the [EN_VSCROLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761689%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and EN_HSCROLL notification messages in conjunction with the WM_VSCROLL and WM_HSCROLL messages.

I found a C++ Builder article that shows what is needed: http://bcbjournal.com/bcbcaq/?loc=edits&caq=29